# What is the difference between @onready and _ready()?

Tags: godot

In Godot 4.x, is declaring @onready variable ***exactly*** the same as declaring it within the _ready() function?

```
@onready var my_variable : = 10

func _ready():
   var my_variable : = 10
```

If not, when/what/how does it make a difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are similar in the sense that both deferred assignment until after the node has entered the tree. However in the example you gave, **they differ with respect to their [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)).**

```
@onready var my_variable : = 10
```

The first example you gave (shown above) has class/script level scope. In other words the variable is considered defined everywhere in that script and can be used to share data between functions.

```
func _ready():
   var my_variable : = 10
```

The second example you gave (repeated above) the variable has function level scope. It is only considered defined & usable on the lines that come after it and **only** within that function.  For example if you try the following:

```
func _ready():
   var player_health : = 10

func take_damage():
   player_health -= 2
```

The result will give an error when the line `player_health -= 2` is reached because the scope of `player_health` is restricted to the `_ready()` function.

---

The example given isn't a particular useful application of `@onready` - there's no clear reason why you might need to defer assigning an int as shown. In contrast, consider the [example in the docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/4.1/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#onready-annotation) of assigning

```
var my_label

func _ready():
    my_label = get_node("MyLabel")
```

Note the key difference: in your example you used the keyword `var` inside the `_ready()` function whereas this here we do not.

In the above case, you *cannot* use a regular assignment because `get_node()` doesn't make sense if the Node has not yet entered the tree. So the code example above waits until the `_ready()` function to assign the value.  Because this pattern is common in Godot, they added some [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) to save us some typing by shortening the above code block to the following:

```
@onready var my_label = get_node("MyLabel")
```

Whether you prefer the single line or the multiline version, they only make sense when you need to make an assignment that cannot be evaluated until after the Node is in the tree.

Answer (score 4):

[Pikalek answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/207052/10408) is correct, but there is more we can say about the difference between `@onready` and `_ready`.

Also it can use a bit of nuance: both `@onready` and `_ready` will run when the `Node` has entered the scene tree... And after `@onready` and `_ready` has run for all children `Node`s... And only the first time... Unless you call `request_ready`, which will make it run again the next time the `Node` enters the scene tree. *You can check `is_node_ready` to know if they already ran.*

*And that is the main difference between using `_tree_entered` (which runs when the `Node` enters the scene tree, no matter what) and `_ready`. The other is that `_tree_entered` runs before `_ready`.*

Now for additional differences (aside from scope):

- What you have in `@onready` will run before `_ready`.
- `@onready` only applies to initializing variables. You can do other things in `_ready`.
- `@onready` is limited to expressions. While `_ready` can have statements.

Something related to scope is lifetime. In this case, local variables only take memory while the method/function (e.g. `_ready`) is running... But fields (class/script level variables) will be stored for the lifetime of the object (the `Node` in this case). In other words, your `@onready` variables will be around until the `Node` is freed (with `free` or `queue_free`).

So when it comes to splitting execution into multiple lines:

- Using `@onready`, since `@onready` statements run in order, you might use the result of prior ones... Yet, the `Node` would be storing those variables for its lifetime.
- Using `_ready`, you don't only can use temporary local variables, but you can also use statements.

Thus, `_ready` is preferible for complex initialization.

---

By the way, as you know, the point of `@onready` is to wait until the scene tree is available before initialization. Consequently any class/script variable without `@onready` is initialized early, but for them accessing the scene tree (e.g. with `get_node`) will fail.

Which begs the question, is there method/function that can be used to do early initialization? And yes, there is: `_init`.